# Ajax posting in mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to post data to controller using ajax post it contains a model and string,the string value comes to the controller but the model is always null.Can anyone help.Attaching the code

```
<script>
function save() {
    var st = "Test";
    var source = ({
        'Name': $('#Name').val(),
        'Code': $('#Code').val(),
        'Address': $('#Address').val(),
        'City': $('#City').val(),
        'State': $('#State').val(),
        'Country': $('#Country').val(),
        'Phone': $('#Phone').val(),
        'Fax':$('#Fax').val()
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:'@Url.Action("Save", "Hospitals")',
        data: { 'st': st, 'hospital': source }
    });
}
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult Save(string st,Hospital hospital)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Hospitals.Add(hospital);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            var dept = db.Departments.ToList();
            ViewBag.department = dept;
        }

        return View(hospital);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Jquery**

```
<script>
function save() {
    var cval;
    var str = "";
    $(".chkmaincat:checked").each(function (i) {
        cval = $(this).val();
        str = str + cval + ",";
    });
    alert(str);
    var source =
    {
        'Name': $('#Name').val(),
        'Code': $('#Code').val(),
        'Address': $('#Address').val(),
        'City': +$('#City').val(),
        'State': $('#State').val(),
        'City': $('#City').val(),
        'Country': $('#Country').val(),
        'Phone': $('#Phone').val(),
        'Fax': $('#Fax').val()
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Hospitals/Save?st='+str,
        data: source
    });

}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Save(string st,Hospital hospital)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Hospitals.Add(hospital);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            var dept = db.Departments.ToList();
            ViewBag.department = dept;
        }

        return View(hospital);
    }
```

by doing the above i'm able to get the string value as well as the modal object.Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use
`data: { 'st': st, 'hospital': JSON.stringify(source) }`

This will convert the variable to be interpretable by the model class in your action method

Comment: hi @muthu thanks for the immediate reply.But it dint work still its showing null value.Any other method for solving the problem?